# Define custom transformation of ggplot axis labels with trans_new function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on percentage changes between periods and struggling with logaritmic transformation of labels. Here is an example based on the `storms` dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- storms |>
  group_by(year) |>
  summarise(wind = mean(wind)) |>
  mutate(lag = lag(wind, n = 1)) |>
  mutate(perc = (wind / lag) - 1) |>
  tidyr::drop_na()
```

I want to visualize the distribution of percentages, making the percentage change symmetrical (log difference) with `log1p`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = log1p(perc))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5)
```

[x-axis with log1p values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs7jE.png)

At this point I wanted to transform the x-axis label back to the original percentage value.
I tried to create my own transformation with `trans_new`, and applied it to the labels in `scale_x_continuous`, but I can't make it work.

```
trans_perc <- trans_new(
  name      = "trans_perc",
  transform = log1p_trans(),
  inverse   = function(x)
    expm1(x),
  breaks    = breaks_log(),
  format    = percent_format(),
  domain    = c(-Inf, Inf)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = log1p(perc))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = trans_perc)
```

Currently, the result is:

> Error in `get_labels()`:
> ! `breaks` and `labels` are different lengths
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I am adding details on the different output I am getting from Alan's first answer:

```
trans_perc <- trans_new(
  name      = "trans_perc",
  transform = log1p,
  inverse   = expm1,
  breaks    = pretty_breaks(5),
  format    = percent_format(),
  domain    = c(-Inf, Inf)
)

library(ggpubr)
a <- ggplot(df, aes(x = log1p(perc))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5)

b <- ggplot(df, aes(x = log1p(perc))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = trans_perc)

c <- ggplot(df, aes(x = perc)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = trans_perc)

ggarrange(a, b, c,
          ncol = 3,
          labels = c("Log on Value only",
                     "Log on Value and X",
                     "Log on X only"))
```

[different outcomes]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCW2m.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the shape of the histogram, but change the labels so that they reflect the value of the `perc` column rather the transformed `log1p(perc)` value. If that is the case, there is no need for a transformer object. You can simply put the reverse transformation (plus formatting) as a function into the `labels` argument of `scale_x_continuous`.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = log1p(perc))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous("Percentage Change", 
                     breaks = log1p(pretty(df$perc, 5)),
                     labels = ~ percent(expm1(.x)))
```

[image]

Note that although the histogram remains symmetrical in shape, the axis labels represent the back-transformed values of the original axis labels.

The point of a transformer object is to do all this for you without having to pass a *transformed* data set (i.e. without having to pass `log1p(perc)`). So in your case, you could do:

```r
trans_perc <- trans_new(
  name      = "trans_perc",
  transform = log1p,
  inverse   = expm1,
  format    = percent_format(),
  domain    = c(-Inf, Inf)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = perc)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = trans_perc)
```

[image]

Which gives essentially the same result

Comment: Thanks Allan for the quick reply. I was looking to the differences of output between transformations of your first answer. This one you edited is the expected outcome.

Comment: @mviolati see my update - I think the second version might be better, since it preserves the shape but shows the logarithmic scale more clearly, with less arbitrary breaks.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! I am still not fully aware of when I need to transform the axis instead of the values, since the approaches are leading to different results...

Comment: @mviolati an axis transformation will affect the "shape" of the data on the plot (it transforms the plotted data as well as the axes). If you have a plot where you are happy with the shape of the data, then you need only change the breaks and labels.

Comment: @mviolati see my edit for a worked example.